# App freezes sometimes when I try to login in facebook

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, freeze

I'm using the android sdk for facebook and I followed the "get started tutorial" in the facebook developers web. Currently I have the following code triggered by a button and it freezes sometimes when it has to display the facebook login dialog.
I wonder why it works sometimes. Am I doing it wrong?

```
Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

    // callback when session changes state
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (session.isOpened()) {
             System.out.println("LOGGED");

        }


        }

 }
  });
```

I also have this in my Activity

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

I can't reach the println statement.